# Read sdio from terminal in event based GUI program

Tags: python, tkinter, event-handling, stdio

Im developing a GUI program in linux using tkinter, the main thread build the window and place buttons with events asociated, then it just joins mainloop and wait for event. Is there a way to generate an event when user writes in program terminal (the one used to open python progrm)? How can i use my event thread to read user inputs and respond? The only alternative is using another thread but i would like to avoid that.

Comment: It is not a good design/practice to use console input in a GUI application.

Comment: You can change `sys.stdin`/`sys.stdout` to your own object that implements `.read`/`.write`. That way you can control what the built in `print`/`input` functions do. Can you give us a minimal example so we can see exactly what you are trying to do?